# How to detect that an Html element is in View?

Tags: jquery, html, height

Using Jquery preferably, how do I detect if an element is within the viewable client area of a browser?

I'm dynamically creating a menu from a dataset, and when the list grows too long, the height of the resulting menu causes part of it to fall below the browser bottom client area. How do I detect this and act accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it should be possible to cook something up using [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) (add [`scrollLeft`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) if your page is prone to horizontal scrolling). Here is some untested sample code that should display a message if the target element is (fully or partially) within the viewport:

```
var pos = $('#element').position(), win = $(window);

if (pos.top < win.height() + win.scrollTop() && pos.bottom > win.scrollTop()) {
    alert('Look at me!');
}
```

The conditions can be swapped around if you care specifically about full visiblity:

```
if (pos.bottom < win.height() + win.scrollTop() && pos.top > win.scrollTop()) {
```

Adding support for horizontal scrolling of the viewport is left as an exercise for the reader :)