# Get image which is in the center of the screen

Tags: jquery

I have a list of images on: http://johanberntsson.se/dev/fotosida/

What would be a good way to get a data attribute from the image thats currently in the center of the screen? Place an invisible line in the center of the screen and see which image that it collides with? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Hope you get the idea, otherwise ill elaborate.

Thanks!

Comment: Cool photos. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229291/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-in-the-view-of-the-user-with-jquery

Comment: @gdoron I think he means the image that is currently in view while scrolling

Comment: ALso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556168/how-to-detect-that-an-html-element-is-in-view

Comment: @Pekka Thanks, and yes it does. Ill have a look at that :)

Comment: @Pekka Do you know if there is a way to decrease the viewport size a bit? To maybe 80% instead of the entire screen?

Comment: You mean resize the browser window?

Comment: @Pekka No, i try to log the image which is currently beeing shown, but at the moment i always (almost) get 2 images with `$(".mainimages:in-viewport")`. See the log on my page for example.

Comment: but that depends on your screen size, doesn't it? You'll have to define which image is *more* "visible"... Possibly using something like Marshall shows below

Comment: @Pekka Yep, ill have a look at that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// finding the center point of the screen
// note that $(window).height() returns the height of the viewport
var center = Math.floor(($(window).height() / 2)) + $(window).scrollTop();

// looping through images and checking each for being in middle
$('.mainimages').each(function(i, img) { 
    var top = $(img).offset().top;
    if(top <= center && top + $(img).height() >= center) {
        // $(img) is in the center
    }
});
```

I don't use jQuery so I'm not certain if there are better methods to use to do this.

Also, not that I do not account for the margin / padding between images. So if you were to do something like put a colored border on the centered image (with no border on others) then there will be moments between images where no image will have a border.

Comment: This is just what i needed. Ill just extend it a bit :) Thanks Marshall!